# "I thought this would look good" in Chinese?

Tags: translation

How would I say "I thought this would look good" in Chinese?

I am specifically looking for the word corresponding to "I thought".

Comment: tried iciba翻译？－＞ 我认为这会看起来很好 seems OK
to emphasize the past might add 早已 between 我 and 认

Comment: some users have some doubts about correctness of above
translation supplied by iciba翻译，in fact the position of 看起来 between 会 and 很好 seems unfamiliar， on the other hand 看起来会很好 appears possible，so that the amended version is 我认为这看起来会很好（you can find many examples of 看起来会很好 on the web）

Answer (score 4):

**Edit: I overlooked the simplified Chinese tag. Now adding simplified chinese version back**

I assume your sentence have a [hidden context]:

I thought it would look good [but it turns out to be awful]

---

In this case I would translate it as:
我以為那會好看(Trad.)/我以为那会好看(Simp.)

To divide it word by word then reverse translate:

(我)(以為)(那)(會)(好)(看)

(I)(thought)(that)(would)(good)(look)

---

Google translate suggested the translation 我認為這會好看(Trad.)/我认为这会好看(Simp.)

But if I reverse translate this back to Eng I would say it is:

(我)(認為)(這)(會)(好)(看)

(I)(**think**)(this)(would)(good)(look)

---

The difference between 认为 and 以为 is not focused on tense, but in tone and assertiveness.

认为 : think, with a sense of confidence in oneself (a.k.a. belief, assert)

以为 : wrongly thinks (a.k.a. thought)

Answer (score 1):

"我曾认为这会很好看".

"曾(céng)" means in the past.